# Ubuntu for a designer?

Tags: wine, adobe, photoshop

I was using Ubuntu few years back but unfortunately I had to move to Windows :( But again I think it's the time to move to Ubuntu with a new computer :)

I'm a web designer, graphic designer. So I love to know, are there any alternatives for **Adobe Photoshop**, **Illustrator** & **Dreamweaver**? I was using those applications with Wine (the windows layer for ubuntu) because *GIMP*, *Inkspace* & *KompoZer* couldn't fill the gap made by Adobe applications. Also Wine doesn't work 100% okay, so it was kinda hard for me to use Ubuntu.

But now I badly want to move with this kind hearted OS. Can anyone please let me know is that possible to fill the gap in Ubuntu which Adobe applications make or will Adobe look at Linux?

Answer (score 2):

if I were you, I would use Virtual Box on Ubuntu. I would install windows on that virtualbox, I would use the required programs for a designer..

Answer (score 1):

At this time, Adobe has no intentions to develop their software for the best operating system. Running these applications in wine is not very stable and usually ends up in crashing and loosing work. :(

I would recommend finding a free and open source alternative to each piece of software. Here are some alternatives to the software you listed:

- Photoshop: GIMP
- Illustrator: Inkscape
- Dreamweaver: (Seriously?) gedit

You may also try running it in a virtual machine, such as Oracle VirtualBox.

Comment: You can't compare Photoshop to Gimp that's like comparing and F1 car to a Golf. It's just not designed to be competing so why compare them?

Comment: If you are a designer then Dreameaver is much easier to use. But if you are a programmer then Gedit is the obvious choice.

Answer (score 1):

I am arquitect, do also some graphics work, and use only Ubuntu. As mentioned in another answer, in some cases you will have to use Wine, or better, Virtual box. Wine is unstable, especially when it comes to print out things etc. 
Format conversion is still the big problem. Sometimes I use pdf-export and later import, to bring drawings from one program to another.

Some programs I use: Inkscape, Gimp, DraftSight for exact technical drawings. It works with standard Autodesk .dwg files, which is fundamental for me.
Cups for printing, has some problems with pdf. Font manager. Kompozer, but it is not being developed, so finally you will have to clean the Html-Code. Libre Office.
Flash is missing. Nothing out there. Synfig is similar, but doesn't import or export Flash-files.
Blender for 3D and 4D animation is great and very complete.
Scribus for publishing. Supports multipage, what Inkscape doesn't do.